# How to call the php function using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using the following script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#view").click(function(){
            var requestId = $("#hdnRequestId").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "enquiryProcess.php",
                data: requestId,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
```

My controller function is

```
<?php
  include('enquiry_function.php');
  $functionObj=new Enquiry();
  if(isset($_POST['requestId']))
  {
    $qt_request_id=$_POST['requestId'];
    $responce=$functionObj->view_enquiry_request($qt_request_id);
    echo json_encode($responce);
  }
?>
```

And my model function is

```
class Enquiry
{
      public function view_enquiry_request($qt_request_id)
    {
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quote_request WHERE qt_request_id='$qt_request_id'");
        $result=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        return $result;
    }
  }
```

I did not get any error.But result in console message is empty.How to get the result from php in jquery ajax.please help me.

Comment: Not sure but maybe you need to add a key in data like this: data: "requestId=" + requestId

Answer (score 1):

Please change

```
var requestId = $("#hdnRequestId").val();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST"
                        , url: "enquiryProcess.php"
                        , data: {"requestId":requestId}
                        , cache: false
                        , success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    });
```

Pass `data` as PlainObject or String or Array. See jQuery documentation here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: The best solution is use JSON as response.